# How to combine row with some condition?

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements, rows

I have dataset like this,

```
> data
    ID    AccessTime   ReferrerCode
    101   01:17:40     910
    103   01:27:53     135
    103   01:33:12     222
    202   02:04:11     921
    202   03:40:30     106 
    103   03:45:02     734
```

And I want to transform my dataset like this,

```
> data
ID   ReferrerCode
101   910
103   135 222
202   921
202   106
103   734
```

My condition is ReferrerCode will be combined if the data has the same ID and the same hour of AccessTime. What should I do to make it happen?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with dput? What format is the access time in? I'd add a column ifentifying the hour and then casting the data with reshape2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the result as `character` in `ReferrerCode` use this:

```
aggregate(ReferrerCode ~ ID + hour(AccessTime), data, FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "))[,c(1,3)]
       ID ReferrerCode
1 101          910
2 103      135 222
3 202          921
4 103          734
5 202          106
```

I assumed that `AccessTime` is in `POSIXlt` format. From `character` you can convert by

```
data$AccessTime <- as.POSIXlt(data$AccessTime, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `base` R solution with `aggregate()`, and `sub()` to extract the hour from `AccessTime`.

```
aggregate(ReferrerCode ~ ID + sub(':.*$', '', AccessTime), c, data=data)[,-2]
#   ID ReferrerCode
#1 101          910
#2 103     135, 222
#3 202          921
#4 103          734
#5 202          106
```